# How do I make Richfaces panel component Resizable

Tags: richfaces

How do I make panel component in richface as resizable in IE browser.
I am using Richface 4.0

Comment: The `<rich:panel>` tag component will be rendered as a div in plain HTML. Search for a way to make a div resizable (javascript + css) and apply it to your panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use  inside a  and set the width of  which you want. See in the code.

```
    <h:panelGrid width="40%">
            <rich:panel header="Test-Panel-Size">
                    <YOUR CODE />
            </rich:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>
```